# Function output in incremental value and display it in html

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I would like to create a Slide Show and its data stored in MySQL database.

```
// SlideShow ----------------------------------------------
mysql_select_db($db,$con);
$qry5 = "SELECT * FROM tblSlider";
$slider_data = mysql_query($qry5,$con);
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($slider_data);
```

then I tried to create a function...

```
function getSlideData(){
   $slideNo = 0;
   global $rowCount;
   if($rowCount == 1 ){
       $slideNo = 0;
   }
   else {
       $slideNo += 1;
   }
   return $slideNo;
  }
```

Now I tried to display it in html Code

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php while ($slideShow = mysql_fetch_array($slider_data)){?>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="<?php getSlideData();?>" class="<?php if ($slideShow['id'] = 1){echo 'active';};?>"></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ol>
```

I have two slide show data in my mysql table and the above code output should be as

```
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
```

but my code output is

```
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="" class="active"></li>
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this without create so much comlexity try this

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <?php 
    $cnt = 0;
    while ($slideShow = mysql_fetch_array($slider_data))
    {
        $cnt+=1;
    ?>
        <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="<?php echo ($cnt-1); ?>" class="<?php if ($cnt == 1){echo 'active';}?>"></li>
  <?php 
  } 
  ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick reply. I am getting the output incrementally but the counter starts from 1 like data-slide-to="1" but I would like to start it from 0. How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First problem is here, you don't echo the return value into the attribute:

```
data-slide-to="<?php echo getSlideData();?>"
                     ^^^^ this is required
```

Second problem is in your if statement, you are doing an assignment (`=`) not a comparison (`==`). So change to:

```
<?php if ($slideShow['id'] == 1){echo 'active';};?>
                           ^^ double ==
```